# Modified Reporting Services Report - RDL does not change?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl

I have a Reporting Services 2005 report that had an error: "Parameter UserID is read-only".  After doing some research, I found a solution that worked.  I opened the report from the Report Manager web interface and changed this:

[image: before]

..to this:

[image: after]

After this change, the report works!  Great!

So, I figure I will download the modified RDL so I can see the change and get the corrected RDL into my source code repository.  So, I download the RDL:

[image: Downloading the RDL]

But my diff tools tell me that the "before" version of the RDL is identical to the "after" version of the RDL.  Convinced that my diff tool was mistaken, I tried another.  Sure enough, there is no difference in the RDL.

What am I missing?  Is the change reflected somewhere other than the RDL, or is Reporting Services not coughing up the correct version of the RDL?  In either case, how can I get the correct version of the RDL?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question mentions ssrs-2005, but you've tagged it ssrs-2008? Either way, I've seen this behavior in both versions I think (but in 2008 for sure).

Comment: SSRS, the server, is very good about not modifying the .rdl. RDL files are modified with BIDS, not by the server. Even when upgrading from 2005 to 2008, the .rdl files are not changed, and you can still get your original (2005) .rdl from SSRS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR Version:** Reporting Services is *not* giving you the correct RDL.

---

Your question prompted me to further investigate a suspicion I already had on SSRS for quite some time: **report parameters can behave in unexpected ways for report developers when deploying (or downloading) report definitions**. One related scenario I had noted before:

1. Create a report with parameters.
2. Deploy the report for the first time.
3. Update the report parameters in some way.
4. Deploy the same report once more.
5. **Result:** parameter settings are *not* succesfully updated on the server.
6. Delete the report from the report manager.
7. Deploy the report once more (effectively the same as step 2).
8. **Result:** Report parameters *are* updated correctly.

In short, if you want to update parameter settings for deployed reports you'll first need to delete it and then deploy it, or update the settings directly via the report manager.

Back to your question(s). You're not missing anything, this just seems the way SSRS is behaving (intended or not). The [RDL schema](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd) has this (abbreviated) piece:

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="ReportParameterType">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="DataType">
            <!-- abbreviated -->
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Nullable" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="DefaultValue" type="DefaultValueType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="AllowBlank" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Prompt" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="ValidValues" type="ValidValuesType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Hidden" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="MultiValue" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="UsedInQuery" minOccurs="0">
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:normalizedString" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

So, there should be a "Hidden" element for your ReportParameter.

I just verified your findings (in SSRS 2008), and think I may have the answer to your second question: **SSRS is indeed *not* coughing up the correct version of the RDL**. It's missing various bits about the parameters, including the element on being hidden or not.

Funny thing is: if you change the report in BIDS and set the parameter to hidden, the RDL *will* be changed and have the `<Hidden>true</Hidden>` element.

Comment: I respectifully disagree with this being "wonky." The RDL is the report definition. Parameters values are not necessarily part of the Report Definition. The .rdl gives beginning default values, but after that these are up to SSRS to keep. This makes a lot of sense when you think about a user that sets up multiple subscriptions for a report with different parameters. If the .rdl is updated, it will continue to use the user's parameters for those subscriptions.

Comment: @JamieF Hmm, good point. Still this was unexpected ("wonky") behavior to me; I expect(ed) the ReportParameter to be part of the Report Definition, not in the least because it *is* in fact in the RDL file when you create/edit the report in BIDS. I'll update my answer and change the word "wonky" into something more semantic :-)

Comment: @Jeroen Still the behavior in v2019. And I vote for 'wonky' because if ssrs is keeping all the subscription param values separate from the defaults, then it should have no trouble changing the defaults when I tell it to.