# SQL query giving conversion error after being deployed to the report server

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssms

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT [Entry No_], [Currency Code], [Posting Date],
       SUM([Credit]), 
       SUM([Debit])
FROM   Db
WHERE  [Posting Date] >= (@DateFrom) 
       AND [Posting Date] <= (@DateTo)
GROUP BY [Entry No_], [Currency Code], [Posting Date]
```

The `[Posting Date]` (which gives an error) is a datetime. My report works in Visual Studio, but when deployed on the Reporting Server:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I have tried setting the dateformat like suggested:

```sql
set dateformat ymd
```

With no success. I've also tried setting Enable Remote Errors to True.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: Are you adding a WHERE clause or a HAVING clause anywhere *(if so, please tell us the clause, the parameters, and the parameter types)*? Or, are you embedding this query in another query *(if so, please tell us the outer query)*? Also, what are the data types of the fields your table? Are you holding dates as strings anywhere *(if so, are you able to fix this)*?

Comment: what is the format of the value of `[Posting Date]`?

Comment: I added the WHERE condition. 
The format for [Posting Date] datetime
All dates are defined as datetime.
Can the Report on RS give problems if the label is a datestring??

Comment: Note that if you've updated the parameter (e.g. the data type) and redeploy the report, the changes to the parameter **are not deployed**. See also [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901099/419956) for some details about that.

Comment: What type is the DateFrom and DateTo param? If they are string you are going to run into issues, and as Jeroen said, updates to the report sometimes don't affect the parameters (as far as I know they update correctly if deployed via Visual Studio, but not if deployed via the 'Update Report' link in Report Manager web interface)

Comment: I have tried to delete the report on RS and deploy it again. With no success. The DateFrom and DateTo are also datetime. 
Going to try deploying via Visual Studio now. 
It´s weird that the error message is "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." when there is no cast/convert to nvarchar for the datetime columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Found the error. 
In MS BIDS the parameters "data type" is automatically set to "Text".
Changing it to "Date/Time" did the charm.

I think it´s kinda odd that the parameter data type does not automatically change to what the column is set to in the database.