# Subreport Performance Difference Between SSRS and BIDS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I've got a report in SSRS that contains two subreports, but it's taking a very long time to show the final report. According to the SSRS Execution Log, the report is spending ~140ms in data retrieval, ~20minutes in processing, and ~20ms in rendering. If I remove either of the subreports (doesn't matter which one), the time drops to ~10minutes for processing. If I remove both subreports, the time drops to ~2s. Quite obviously I have to do something about the subreports; probably try to integrate them into the main report.

Does the "TimeDataRetrieval" statistic in the execution log represent the aggregate data retrieval time for the report and all subreports, or is it just for the main report (meaning the data retrieval times for subreports are actually being added to the "TimeProcessing" stat)?

Furthermore, when I run the main report within BIDS (Visual Studio), the entire report returns in a couple seconds. Why would a report + 2 subreports render completely within a couple seconds in BIDS, yet the exact same thing takes around 20 minutes when viewed from the reporting server? They are both accessing the same SQL DB (data retrieval is only 140ms from SSRS server), and the SSRS/SQL server should have plenty of power (running in an 8-core VM that doesn't break 1% CPU usage).

Comment: Can you run the subreport on its own (e.g. from the ReportViewer) and then check the "TimeDataRetrieval"? Also, are there any parameters at play for the subreports? If the parameters have changed since first deployment, the BIDS version may have the updates but the deployed version hasn't gotten it yet (since re-deploying won't change the parameter settings).

Comment: TimeDataRetrieval for either subreport is ~2s (with ~700 rows in the main report, would this mean total run time = 700*2?). There is only one parameter for each subreport, but they haven't changed. My method of deployment is to go to http://server/Reports and click the "Upload File", then upload the rdl file. Does this force an update of the parameters on the deployed version?

Comment: Not sure, but I think it will not (similar to the situation from [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901099/419956)). But if the subreports on their own run fast on their own from the Web Report Viewer then there's something else at play it seems. Have you tried deleting the reports on the server, and redeploying them from scratch?

Comment: Deleted the main report and two subreports using the Reports browser on the server, then uploaded the three rdl files using the Reports browser. It is still taking around 15 minutes to run. I double checked the DB connections between SSRS server and BIDS, and they are the same.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. Sounds like there may be a problem very specific to your situation. A binary-search-debug-session may be your final option left.

Comment: @AdamDunn have you had any luck in fixing the performance issue? I have a few questions - have you verified that parameter values are the same between your testing and the deploy for ALL 3 reports? BIDS caches the result set when the parameters and result set do not change. This could be why BIDS performance is so much better. Have you tried running again in BIDS after deleting the <reportname>.data file?

Comment: @AdamDunn also, have you tried deploying only the main report to the server and comparing the performance, then only one of the subreports, then the other to try to determine if just one of the reports is causing the problem?

Comment: @AdamDunn some info on TimeDataRetrieval and other SSRS metrics: http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/07/more-tips-to-improve-performance-of.html