# How to prevent parameter error for NULL dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, null, footer

I developed an RDL file with a parameter set to be the field value, named "Client", of one of my datasets.  I use this parameter value in the page footer because this was the only way I could get Client to appear correctly in the footer.  The other methods Client value did not always appear correctly.

Here is what this parameter properties look like:
[image]

So this works if there is data, however, if there are no records in rpt_rd_RecreationTherapy, then I get the following error:
[image]

and in my page footer, I have a text box set to the following:

```
=iif(isnothing(Parameters!new_youth.Value),"",Parameters!new_youth.Value)
```

Yes, I checked "allow blank value" to my parameter configuration

Comment: You are running the report through IE, as I can see. Set visibility to Visible for testing purposes.

Comment: You *may* have fallen victim to a "feature" of SSRS deployment: parameter settings [do not get updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900505/modified-reporting-services-report-rdl-does-not-change/12901099#12901099) except for the first initial deployment. @eestein's suggestion may help finding out if that's the case (though changing visibility will be equally tough, requiring changes through the web front-end or deleting and then re-deploying the report).

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen is probably correct.  I would access the Reports, Parameter setting using Report Manager and update it to match the BIDS setting.